# Fixing knockout multiple bindings on JQM ajax single page navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, knockout.js

Am working on a windows 8 phonegap application. Am using JQuery, JQuery Mobile, Knockout JS for the same. Am kindof stuck at the universal error

"**you cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element**"

Googling gave me two solutions.

***1)Ko.cleanNode (Which was not advisable)***

***2)Templating (Recommended approach)***

I was trying to go with the recommended templating approach but still I was encountering the same error.

Following is my javascript logic:

```
//Code for home.js

//My View model
function HomeViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.MyDaySchedule = [
        { picture: "../../images/home/MyDaySchedule_video.png" },
        { day: "2", title: "Physical Activity after surgery", text: "you will have tasks each day to help gain strength. Complete self-assessments...", picture: "../../images/home/MyDaySchedule_b1.png" }
    ];
}
//Main Execution
function initialize() {
    console.log("Knockout activated");
    // Activates knockout.js

    ko.applyBindings(new HomeViewModel(), document.getElementById("#homePage"));
}
```

I will call the initialize function inside my pageshow event. The binding will happen properly without any error and all data values will get displayed on running the application.

Following is my html code with the template based approach:

```
//home.html
//Binding one
   <div data-bind="template: { name: 'frame1data1-template', data: MyDaySchedule[0] }">  </div>
                            <script type="text/html" id="frame1data1-template">
                                <!-- Displays the "picture" field. -->
                                <img data-bind="attr:{src: picture}"
                                     id="frame1data1_img" draggable="false" />
                            </script>


//Binding two
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'frame1data2-template', data: MyDaySchedule[1] }"></div>
                            <script type="text/html" id="frame1data2-template">
                                <img data-bind="attr:{src: picture}"
                                     src="#" id="frame1data2_img" draggable="false" />
                                <h1 id="frame1data2_daytext" class="disabletextselect">Day</h1>
                                <h1 id="frame1data2_dayvalue" class="disabletextselect" data-bind="text:day"></h1>
                                <h1 id="frame1data2_title" class="disabletextselect" data-bind="text:title"></h1>
                                <h1 id="frame1data2_text" class="disabletextselect" data-bind="text:text"></h1>
                                <input type="button" id="frame1data2_backpicture" data-role="none">
                            </script>
```

Consider on clicking any of the above image I navigate to new.html using $.mobile.navigate("new.html"); (Which happened flawlessly)

And my error occurs when I navigate back from new.html to home.html using window.history.back(); which throwed me the error "**you cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element**" cause that ko.applyBindings() is called again inspite of me using the templating approach.

Is there a positive and suitable workaround for this error for my example?.

Comment: I think when you navigate back to home page, binding is already there( in cache) and again your initialize method called and it shows the error of multiplebinding.so you can call Ko.cleanNode() before ko.applyBindings or another thing you can do check for fresh call or window.history.back call. it is fresh call then only make ko.applybinding.

Comment: Ko.cleanNode() will work.. but I have to pass the page top element(container) as element to ko.cleanNode() which is freezing some css based interactions. Am looking for an alternative to Ko.cleanNode() such as the templating approach which I have used here. And to your comment...am also using window.history.back only in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I would put your individual page view models inside of your root view model. Then just applyBindings with the root view model once and use the `data-bind="with: HomeViewModel()"` for the home page template, and the same for other pages.